# facebook connect set status error

Tags: php, facebook

When I update status from facebook connect, following error occur

> Uncaught exception
>   'FacebookRestClientException' with
>   message 'Updating status requires the
>   extended permission status_update'

I also allow permission with

```
<script>
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("offline_access", function(perms) {
   if (!perms) {
     //continue_without_permission();
   } else {
     //save_session();

   }
 });
</script>
```

My PHP code is

```
$res=$fb->api_client->call_method("facebook.status.set",array('uid'=>$uid,'status'=>'set message from facebook connect api'));
```

Update:

I change with javascript like that

```
location.href="http://www.facebook.com/authorize.php?api_key=<?= $appapikey ?>&v=1.0&ext_perm=status_update&next=http://www.site.com/fbconnect.php&next_cancel=http://www.site.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're only prompting for the "offline_access" permission. It's telling you you need to prompt for the "status_update" permission (*Updating status requires the extended permission status_update*) to set status. Check the permissions [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions) but it's likely just:

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("status_update,offline_access", permissionHandler);
```

Note that you can [send more than one permission type](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog) to the dialog.